# Does the communication channel breaks in between client and server if we introduce a load balancer in SignalR?

Tags: signalr

I am new to SignalR and I have a question on SignalR communication when we introduce a load balancer.

Lets assume we want to execute a void method on server side which receives some data as a parameter from client. Server takes that data and processes further. Lets say after processing for a while, it identifies that it has to send the notification back to client.

Case 1(Between client and server): Client calls void method on server side(Hub) by passing some data. Connection gets disconnected. Server processes the client data further. When it identifies that it has to push the notification back to client, it recreates the connection and pushes back the data to client.

Case 2(Between client and server with load balancer in between): How does the above scenario(Case 1) work here?. When server sends the push notification back to load balancer after processing client data, how does it know to which client it has to send the notification back?

Answer (score 0):

You should read the [scaleout docs](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-in-signalr). Short version: messages get sent to all servers, so if the client reconnects (it's not the server that establishes the connection!) before the connection times out , it will get the message.

Quote from the docs:

> The cursor mechanism works even if a client is routed to a different
>   server on reconnect. The backplane is aware of all the servers, and it
>   doesn’t matter which server a client connects to.

Comment: Hi Lars, Thanks for the quick response. I have gone through the scaleout docs and my understanding is that it is helpful in broadcasting scenario. However  I want the message to be send back to only caller. Client connects to server via load balancer, server takes some time to process the request. When server wants to send back the data to caller(Client), it has to go via load balancer(LB). However LB doesn't know to which client it has to send the data back as it doesn't have any history and the connection made earlier is no longer available. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: if the client reconnects (to any server), then it will have the same connection id and the server will know where to send the message; if the connection times out, then this won't work and you'll have to map the user to the new connection and resend the message, but it's no different than with a single server